# xgboost out of bag predictions

Tags: r, random-forest, xgboost

is it possible to get the out-of-bag (oob) predictions of each tree, and plot some kind of confidence intervals.

For example this is implemented in the `quantregForest` package:

```
data(ozone,package="gss")
library(quantregForest)
xozone <- ozone[-1]
yozone <- ozone$upo3
qrfozone <- quantregForest(xozone,yozone)
plot(qrfozone)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not implemented yet in xgboost. I think the difficulty is, that in randomForest each tree is weighted equally, while in boosting methods the weight is very different. Also it is (still) not very usual to "bag" xgboost models and only then you can generate out of bag predictions (see here for how to do that in xgboost: http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/R-package/discoverYourData.html#special-note-what-about-random-forests).

In future that would be a nice tool to be implemented in xgboost. Also if you think about fast tuning with oob predictions.